# how to find intersections between multiple sets and a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have multiple sets as win conditions in my tic tac toe game:

```
    win1 = {1,2,3}
    win2 = {4,5,6}
    win3 = {7,8,9}
    win4 = {1,5,9}
    win5 = {7,5,3}
    win6 = {1,4,7}
    win7 = {2,5,8}
    win8 = {3,6,9}
```

where each number is a position on the tic tac toe grid. I also have a list that adds every position the O and the X player makes. My current way of checking if a player won is this:

```
    def checker():
      if (win1 or win2 or win3 or win4 or win5 or win6 or win7 or win8).issubset(jonesO):
        print 'O wins!'
        return 0
      elif (win1 or win2 or win3 or win4 or win5 or win6 or win7 or win8).issubset(jonesX):
        print 'X wins!'
        return 1
      elif (tie).issubset(bob):
        print 'IT IS A TIE!!!!!'
        return 2
```

but I figured out that the .issubset only checks the first set and nothing else. How do I change it so all the sets in the elif() and if are checked as subsets?

Comment: `win1 or win2 or win3 or win4 or win5 or win6 or win7 or win8` will evaluate to the first non empty `winX` in the sequence.

Comment: Have you cheked the actual result of `(win1 or win2 or win3 or win4 or win5 or win6 or win7 or win8)`? BTW you found a rather complex way of representing the gane and checking the win conditions. I'd present it as a two dimmensional list, just the the it is.

Comment: Yeah I tried the (win1 or win2 or win3... win8) and it only checks the first win condition. So if I had the second win condition nothing would happen. What do you mean by presenting it as a two d list, just the the it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `a or b or c` evaluates to the first of the three that is truthy (if none is truthy, it is the last). In your case that would be the first non-empty `set`: `win1`. For your case, you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(x.issubset(jonesO) for x in (win1, win2, win3, win4, win5, win6, win7, win8)):
    print 'O wins!'
```

Comment: I was just about to ask you to explain how "or" operator works on non-booleans, but you did it already. You have my upvote (and my axe!).

Comment: I tested your solution and it works! Could you explain why there is a x.issubset(jonesO)?

Comment: @JerryZhou It is part of the generator expression `(fnc(x) for x in y)` that iterates the results of function `fnc` to all elements `x` of some iterable `y`. So, `x` is the loop varibale in that expression that takes on the values `win1`, `win2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**isSubSet** is costly operation, you should instead use **union** operator of set.

```
any(jonesO==jonesO.union(x) for x in (win1, win2, win3, win4, win5, win6, win7, win8))
```

This condition will return **True** if any of winning combination is part of moves set else will return **False**.

Basically, union of two set will return same set if joining set is already a subset of other set